# Eliminate zero counts bin from histogram

Tags: r, histogram

I have an histogram of a random variable **X1** with some zero counts bins:

```
 > histograms$X1
 $breaks
 [1] 30.23106 30.31956 30.40806 30.49656 30.58505 30.67355 30.76205 30.85055 30.93905 31.02755 31.11605
[12] 31.20455 31.29305 31.38154 31.47004 31.55854 31.64704 31.73554 31.82404 31.91254 32.00104 32.08954
[23] 32.17804 32.26653 32.35503 32.44353 32.53203 32.62053 32.70903 32.79753 32.88603

$counts
 [1]   1   0   0   0   1   1   4  11  13  34  66  71  89 131 234 314 174  52  26   5   3   1   0   0   0   0
[27]   0   0   0   1
```

[..]

I need to feed this histogram to an uncertainty quantification (UQ) code. By "feeding" I mean that I copy the `breaks` and `counts` vectors and paste them in the input file of the UQ code. Now, the input format of the UQ code has a couple quirks:

1. It wants `breaks` and `counts` to be the same length,
   with the last element of `counts` being a 0, so I add a 0 at the end
   of `counts`.
2. (much worse) it doesn't accept 0 count bins (except for the last fictitious 0    of point 1 above). So I have to eliminate by hand the 0 elements of `counts`, and the corresponding elements of `breaks` (is this correct?).

I get:

```
30.23106 30.58505 30.67355 30.76205 30.85055 30.93905 31.02755 31.11605 31.20455 31.29305 31.38154 31.47004 31.55854 31.64704 31.73554 31.82404 31.91254 32.00104 32.08954 32.79753 32.88603

1  1   1   4  11  13  34  66  71  89 131 234 314 174  52  26   5   3   1  1 0
```

Now, I definitely don't want to do this by hand, for each random variable I need to feed to the UQ code. Is there a way I could automate this?

**EDIT** I took the very good answer I received and put it in a function, in case someone else needs something similar.

```
CleanHistData = function(histograms, variable){
     HistList=histograms[[variable]]
     idx=HistList$counts!=0
     breaks=HistList$breaks[idx]
     counts=c(HistList$counts[idx], 0)
     res=data.frame(breaks=breaks,counts=counts)
     return(res)
}

> res=CleanHistData(histograms,"X1")
> res$breaks
[1] 30.23106 30.58505 30.67355 30.76205 30.85055 30.93905 31.02755 31.11605 31.20455 31.29305 31.38154
[12] 31.47004 31.55854 31.64704 31.73554 31.82404 31.91254 32.00104 32.08954 32.79753 32.88603
> res$counts
[1]   1   1   1   4  11  13  34  66  71  89 131 234 314 174  52  26   5   3   1   1   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to create these variables.

First, create an index for `counts` not equal 0.

```
idx <- as.logical(counts)
```

Second, extract corresponding breaks.

```
breaks <- histograms$X1$breaks[idx]
```

Finally, extract corresponding counts and add final 0.

```
counts <- c(histograms$X1$counts[idx], 0)
```

Comment: Excellent! I wrapped that into a function so that I can quickly get my vectors without having to rewrite the sequence of instructions for each random variable, and I put it in the question (putting it here in the comment made it unreadable). Thanks!